# Grails 3.2.13 Spring Framework Version

Tags: spring, grails

If I'm using Grails 3.2.13 what version of Spring Framework should I be using?  What version of spring is grails 3.2.13 built on top of?

Answer (score 2):

According to the dependency section of the [documentation](https://docs.grails.org/3.2.13/guide/introduction.html#dependencyUpgrades) for that version, it uses Spring Framework 4.3.1

Comment: `./gradlew dependencies` would also reveal it :)